# sql LIKE and NOT Equal in single query, not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `table1` with two coloumns "id" and "name".
The values are :

```
id       name
----------------
(A1001   abc)
(A1002   bcd)
(A1003   cde)
(A1004   def)
```

I'm trying this query:

```
select distinct id,name
 from table1
 where id like '%1%' or name like '%c%' and id <> 'A1002'
```

It is not working. I want to get all the id and names that are like '1' or 'c' but want to exclude the row whose id is 'A1002'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parenthesis, `and` has higher precedence than `or`.

```
select distinct id,name
 from table1
 where (id like '%1%' or name like '%c%') and id <> 'A1002'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some brackets...

```
SELECT id,name 
FROM table1 
WHERE (id LIKE '%1%' OR name LIKE '%c%') AND id <> 'A1002'
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the distinct keyword. The ids make the rows distinct anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct id,name from table1 where (id like '%1%' or name like '%c%') and id <> 'A1002'
```

What about braces? you mixed the `and` and  `or`